# spring boot retry with RabbitMQ

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rabbit

I want to user Spring's retry on failed message processing when receiving messages from RabbitMQ.

Do I need to set requeue=true in order to for the message after several retries to end up in dead letter exchange?

Does retry means that the message is sent back to queue each time the processing is failed?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of properties related to retry; see [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-using-amqp-receiving).

You can add a `RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer` bean to cause the message to be routed to the DLQ when retries are exhausted.